# React Firebase Link a facebook account with a google account with same mail id

Tags: reactjs, firebase, oauth

I am using firebase in my react app for sigin/signup. The issue I am facing is that once I created an account using google and I try login with a facebook account with same mail id. I will get `auth/account-exists-with-different-credential` error. So in this case I want combine both account together in firebase and keep as a single auth user. I tried using `linkWithPopup` but it throws the following error - `FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/popup-blocked)`. When I try with `linkWithRedirect` it is getting linked but I am not getting any result data in the frontend like access token, email etc. I was searching a solution in internet but most of them are using an older version of firebase. My version is `"firebase": "^9.21.0"` . So if anyone can give me a sample code or redirect me to a proper solution link it will be great help.